# Does manipulating MySQL data using React Native Application possible?

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, react-native

I'm about to create a React Native mobile application that can manipulate data to a remote MySQL database (cloud / not in mobile) without using PHP (back-end) at all. Is it possible or not?

Comment: _Just a note:_ Mobile applications can be decompiled. If your app is decompiled, your database credentials would be exposed, leaving your database vulnerable and open for attack.

Comment: My bad, so a php back-end is necessary. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't necessary be PHP though. It can be any server side language. The important thing is to build a proper API with good security and user roles.

Answer (score 0):

it's not necessary you use a web service connecting to a database (but it is recommended).
In my case, I wrote a native module(Android https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html ) and then used JDBC to connect with a mysql server. Add this line to your gradle dependency (in case of android)

```
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.44'
```

and code in the same way as you do for a simple java jdbc program, you can connect to a database and perform operations on it. If you need further clarity please comment.